# Making an array bindable in a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make component where you can click on some buttons, and then the button gets active. I am very new to REACT but AFAIK if you want to use variables in the render method you need to apply variable as hooks by using useState. And I think that is where I go wrong here. The code below does not update the active attribute on the button when clicked only on load. In angular we would just change the property in the array, how do I achieve this with REACT?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from "reactstrap";

const TimeBar = props => {
  const buttons = [
    { id: 1, title: "10 min", minutes: 10, isActive: true },
    { id: 2, title: "1 hour", minutes: 60, isActive: false },
    { id: 3, title: "6 hours", minutes: 360, isActive: false },
    { id: 4, title: "12 hours", minutes: 720, isActive: false },
    { id: 5, title: "24 hours", minutes: 1440, isActive: false }
  ];

  function clicked(button) {
    button.isActive = true;
    alert(button.minutes);
  }

  return (
    <ButtonGroup>
      {buttons.map(button => (
        <Button
          key={button.id}
          onClick={() => clicked(button)}
          color="secondary"
          size="sm"
          active={button.isActive}
        >
          {button.title}
        </Button>
      ))}
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
};

export default TimeBar;
```

Comment: use the `useState` hook you imported https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work with hooks by using [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) in this particular case.

In [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) documentation you can read further about how to use `setState()` as well which is called in your code `setButtons` and why you need to mutate the previous state instead of directly.

Like the following:

```
const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
   { id: 1, title: "10 min", minutes: 10, isActive: true },
   { id: 2, title: "1 hour", minutes: 60, isActive: false },
   { id: 3, title: "6 hours", minutes: 360, isActive: false },
   { id: 4, title: "12 hours", minutes: 720, isActive: false },
   { id: 5, title: "24 hours", minutes: 1440, isActive: false }
]);

const clicked = (button) => {
   setButtons(prevState => {        
       return prevState.map(e => {
           if (e.id === button.id) { e.isActive = true; }
           return e;
       })  
   });
}
```

Or in `clicked` event you can do the following:

```
const clicked = (button:any) => {
   setButtons((prevState:any) => {        
      const newState = [...prevState];
      newState.find(e => e.id === button.id).isActive = true;
      return newState;
   });
}
```

Suggested documentation to read: [Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Worked. Thanks highly appreciated. Did not know you could add arrays in to the useState.

Comment: Would it be same approach if you had hundreds of rows or buttons? Seems pretty dramatic to return a complete new array because one value changes. As stated in angular you would just change the property on the single object.

Comment: @ThomasSegato There is an algorithm in React called reconciliation which updates only that part of the DOM which has been changed. So technically only that `<Button>`'s change will be commited to the DOM where `isActive` property has changed, all the other `<Button>` elements remain the same. Read further here: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html I hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Personally I'd suggest something like `const index = newState.indexOf(button); newState[index] = { ...button, isActive: true }; return newState;` so you're not mutating the original object reference, and then you can safely define the initial array literal outside of the function component so it doesn't have to be initialized on every single render pass.